# KeyboardInterrupt exception

Tags: python, python-2.x

Вопрос:

Как повторить строку `Attempts left: 0. Are you sure you want to exit? (y/N):` если мы введем любой другой знак вместо `n/N` или `y/Y`, а не продолжить цикл?

Задача:

Используя обработку исключений, создайте скрипт, который выводит текущее время каждые 10 секунд в бесконечном цикле.

При нажатии Ctrl-C (KeyboardInterrupt exception) скрипт должен обработать исключение и распечатать количество попыток, оставшихся до выхода (по умолчанию 3), и уменьшить счетчик попыток. Когда счетчик достигнет 0, скрипт должен запросить выбор «Are you sure you want to exit? y/N".

[image: пример потока]

Вывод функции через Terminal в PyCharm.

```
import datetime
import time

def current_time():
    while datetime.datetime.now():
        time.sleep(10)
        print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

def exception(number_of_requests):
    count = number_of_requests
    while True:
        try:
            current_time()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            if count > 1:
                count -= 1
                print ('{}: {}'.format('Attempts left', count))
            elif count == 1:
                warning = raw_input('Attempts left: 0. Are you sure you want to exit? (y/N): ')
                if warning == "y" or warning == 'Y':
                    print('Exit')
                    break
                elif warning == 'n' or warning == 'N':
                    try:
                        current_time()
                    except KeyboardInterrupt:
                        warning = raw_input('Attempts left: 0. Are you sure you want to exit? (y/N): ')
                        if warning == "y" or warning == 'Y':
                            print('Exit')
                            break


exception(3)
```

Comment: Ну во-первых, вынести ввод в отдельную функцию, потому что он у вас повторяется два раза. Во-вторых, обернуть его в ещё один такой же `while True` и break'ать его только если ввели yYnN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать функции тут не обязательно. Так код должен быть понятнее.

`\r` перед выводом для того, чтобы не было `^C` (Ctrl-C).

```
from datetime import datetime
import time


count = 2
work = True

while work:
    try:
        print datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        time.sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if count:
            print "\rAttempts left:{}".format(count)
            count -= 1
        else:
            while True:

                resp = raw_input('\rAttempts left: 0. Are you sure you want to exit? (y/N): ')

                if resp.lower() == 'y':
                    print "Exit"
                    work = False
                    break
                elif resp.lower() == 'n':
                    break
```

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!